# Excel: Automatic series with scatter plot

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a 3-columns table (Date,Time,Value). I would like to automatically plot the table using the following format:

- X-axis:  Time
- Y-axis:  Value
- Series:  Date

This would give me a different line for each day.

I only managed to do it manually (adding a new series for each day), yet I want it to be automatic, i.e. create a new line for every new value in the first column.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind a little coding, you could try something like this:

[VBA to Split Data Range into Multiple Chart Series](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/vba-to-split-data-range-into-multiple-chart-series/)

Comment: Ok, seems fine to me, it would be great if I could trigger the macro on external data update. Is that possible?

Comment: You could call the code from within a Worksheet_TableUpdate, Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate, Worksheet_Change, or Worksheet_Calculate event.